# Rename the tag "asp.net-core-webapi21" to "asp.net-core-webapi-2.1"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

To moderators, please rename the tag "[asp.net-core-webapi21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-webapi21)" to "[asp.net-core-webapi-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-webapi-2.1)"

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself? There are only 4 questions in there, you have 2K rep so the edits don't need to go through the queue. The tag will delete itself after there are no questions in it for a day.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, this is why I ask ) thanks